# Can't resolve 'dns' in 'node_modules/mongodb/lib'

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When running `npm start` to start my React Application, after installing MongoDB, it throws the error that it can't resolve 'dns' in the node_modules, previously, I have tried running `npm install dns` but further errors flooded my command line, has anyone else come across this error? Is there a known solution?

Comment: Running into this issue to.